# How to get today's date in mm/dd/yyyy format into a datetime variable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want today's date in mm/dd/yyyy format from a DateTime variable. How to get it?
I need to check this with some date variable so it must be also in date variable format?plz help

Ex: i need to get today date in mm/dd/yyyy format and i already date which is datetime datatype in mm/dd/yyyy format and i have to compare them

Comment: Note: a DateTime variable stores a Date, independent of format. The "format" only applies when you convert it to string (display it).

Comment: Note that DateTime.Today returns just the date with a time of 00:00:00 where DateTime.Now returns the date and the current time.

Comment: What you mean with the '**ex:**' part of your question is unclear to me. As mentioned several times a `DateTime` object has **no format** and can be thought of as a number. This 'number' can be compared to other 'numbers' (`DateTime`-variables) and this will allow you to compare dates. **Only** *if you convert to a string you will have a 'formatted date'*.

Comment: Please google out some information.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `DateTime.Today`:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // As DateTime
string s_today = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // As String
```

*Edit:* You edited your post to add another question, so here comes my edit to supply at least some sort of answer.

**Update** While you can use `DateTime.Compare()` you should use plain comparisson:

```
if(today < otherdate)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `DateTime`-variables to check against other `DateTime`-variables using the `DateTime.Compare()` method. Both otpions will work and it comes down to preference and what you want to do with the result.

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(today, otherdate);

if(result < 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Today is earlier than the 'otherdate'");
elseif(result > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Today is later than the 'other date'");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Dates are equal...");
```

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");`
`Console.Write(DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")); -> 05.10.2015`

Answer (score 4):

```
string datestring = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert DateTime variable to string in the specified format:

```
DateTime d = ...;
string s = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

---

If you want to compare only date part of DateTime, not time part:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("10/10/2011");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011");

if (d1.Date > d2.Date)
{
   // do the stuff
}
```

Comment: @Shafi: Post a comment to a post, don't propose an edit of that post

Answer (score 2):

MSDN say: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: They both do the same thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse is what you are looking for...